# Magic Square Algorithm Issue

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am following de la Loubere's algorithm and am attempting to code it into a successful algorithm for my Magic Square program. I am following these steps:

1) The number '1' goes in the middle of the top row.

2) All numbers are then placed one column to the right and one row up from the previous number.

3) Whenever the next number placement is above the top row, stay in that column and place the number in the bottom row.

4) Whenever the next number placement is outside of the rightmost column, stay in that row and place the number in the leftmost column.

5) When encountering a filled-in square, place the next number directly below the previous number.

6) When the next number position is outside both a row and a column, place the number directly beneath the previous number.

However, I am not getting the desired output of numbers. (That is, the numbers are not in the correct places or are registering as zeros.)

Any help would be appreciated.(For some reason in the above code the last angle bracket is outside the code block. However this is not the issue.)

Edit: I have edited the code based on suggestion, however I am still finding the same error:

```
void magic(unsigned int n){//Takes in size of square (User input)
unsigned int magicSq[15][15];
unsigned int sizeSquared = n * n; 
int i = 0, j = n/2; //the initial position according to de la Loubere's algorithm
unsigned int indexer; //What we are going to use to iterate through

//Using de la Loubere's algorithm for odd # magic squares
for (indexer = 1; indexer <= sizeSquared; indexer++){
    magicSq[i][j] = indexer;
    i--; //Decrement the row (one row up)
    j++; //Increment the column (One column to the right)

    //First ensure with if and else if that i and j are in bounds.
    if (i < 0){//If row goes higher than top row
        i += n; //i is set to bottom row
    }

    else if(j == n){//If number placement is outside of rightmost column
        j -= n; //Maintain row and place # in leftmost column.
    }

    else{
        if (magicSq[i][j] != 0 || (i < 0 && j ==n )){//If the magic square has a number in it
                                            //Or is outside both row and column
            i++; //Place the number one below the previous number 
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Great to hear. If you leave the question as it is, it may help other people with the same or similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (magicSq != 0 || (i < 0 && j ==n )){//If the magic square has a number in it
```

Your code doesn't match your comment here.  `magicSq` is always going to be non-zero. you want `magicSq[i][j]!=0`.

But before you can do that test, or any test, first check that `i` and `j` are in bounds, and adjust if needed.

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be the problem is that you move 1 step up and to the right first, and then move 1 step down if you hit another number. With that approach, you should actually move 2 steps down and 1 step left, to end up 1 step below your original position. I have modified the logic a bit, and this seems to be working:

```
for (indexer = 1; indexer <= sizeSquared; indexer++){
    //If the magic square has a number in it, redo move and go one down
    if (magicSq[i][j] != 0){            
        i += 2;
        j -= 1;
    }
    magicSq[i][j] = indexer;
    if (i == 0 && j == n - 1) //if in top right corner, move down
        i++;
    else{
        i--; //Decrement the row (one row up)
        j++; //Increment the column (One column to the right)
    }
    if (i < 0){//If row goes higher than top row
        i += n; //i is set to bottom row
    }
    else if (j == n){//If number placement is outside of rightmost column
        j -= n; //Maintain row and place # in leftmost column.
    }
}
```

On a 3x3 square, I get the result:

```
8 1 6
3 5 7
4 9 2
```